# Avisynth+ How to install

Tags: avisynth

My system is windows 7 64 bit, Avisynth+ 3.6.0 is installed.

Displayed when loading 64-bit dll:

Cannot load a 64 bit DLL in 32 bit Avisynth: 'D:/Program Files/AviSynthPlus/plugins64+/avss.dll'

Answer (score 0):

Your path `D:/Program Files/AviSynthPlus/plugins64+/` is by AviSynth recognized as an autoload path for *32-bit plugins,* because this path is set (as a value) *in an inappropriate registry key.*

Launch Registry Editor and check / change path values in these keys:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Avisynth\PluginDir+` for 64-bit version,
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Avisynth\PluginDir+` for 32-bit version.

or (lower priority)

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Avisynth\PluginDir+` for 64-bit version,
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Avisynth\PluginDir+` for 32-bit version.

Comment: But the version according to OP is 3.6.0 which is the release from May 2020. Your link points to sth. way older. Have you mixed up things?

Comment: You're right, thanks. Version which I meant was then bumped to 3.4.0 and continues with this form of version numbering.

Comment: The problem now is that 64-bit avisynth does not work.

Comment: Please specify in details what does it mean “does not work”.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run 64bit plugins in a 32bit application - that's what the error, you got, tells us. You should install or build the 64bit version of avisynth as this should be able to work with the plugins.

Also Windows 7 is unsupported by Microsoft. The longer you wait with upgrading to Windows 10 (or using another modern OS) the more problems you will face.

Comment: I installed 32-bit and 64-bit avisynth
(AviSynthPlus_3.6.0_20200520_vcredist), this is not wrong. Why is it displayed 32 bit

Comment: You have a path D:\Program Files\ where the 64bit version should be but do you also have D:\Program Files (x86)\ where the 32 bit version is?  Maybe sth. during installation went wrong and they both installed in the same location?